# MySQL Query not returning any results

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to understand why my query isn't returning any results, please could you take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM sys_online_users WHERE last_active BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to show which users have been active within  the last 10 seconds or any other time interval. However when I run the query I get no results, despite knowing that I have got updates in my table between the specified time range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yiu are going the wrong way with the between- first the ten seconds ago, and afterwards the now:

```
SELECT * FROM sys_online_users WHERE 
last_active BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),
INTERVAL 10 SECOND) 
AND NOW()
```

Comment: I now noticed that for some reason the PHP that is writting the active time to my DB is an hour behind, that is also probably why I couldn't get and matches earlier, but now to add to the question, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys_online_users WHERE last_active BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

Only columns placement error, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys_online_users WHERE last_active BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECOND) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below query it is working perfect.In your query please take more gap with second then fire query you will get desired result

SELECT * FROM sys_online_users WHERE last_active BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 SECOND) AND NOW();

In this query  i have added 50 second so we can identify easily.